# JqPlot not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have simple web application where there is nothing I have in src folder of eclipse and I have maintained one NEwfile.html in Webcontent folder of eclipse.And i have "plugins" folder under the webcontent where is stored my javascript files.

here is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chat3" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var s1 = [2, 6, 7, 10];
var s2 = [7, 5, 3, 4];
var s3 = [14, 9, 3, 8];
plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [s1, s2, s3], {
    // Tell the plot to stack the bars.
stackSeries: true,
captureRightClick: true,
seriesDefaults:{
renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
rendererOptions: {
          // Put a 30 pixel margin between bars.
barMargin: 30,
          // Highlight bars when mouse button pressed.
          // Disables default highlighting on mouse over.
highlightMouseDown: true   
},
pointLabels: {show: true}
},
axes: {
xaxis: {
renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
},
yaxis: {
padMin: 0
}
},
legend: {
show: true,
location: 'e',
placement: 'outside'
}     
});
  // Bind a listener to the "jqplotDataClick" event.  Here, simply change
  // the text of the info3 element to show what series and ponit were
  // clicked along with the data for that point.
$('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataClick',
function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
$('#info3').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
}
);
});


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jqplot requires jQuery, but you're not loading `jquery.js`.

Comment: I included that too but still it is not displaying..please check my updated code

Comment: Have you checked the Javascript console for errors?

Comment: there is no error i feel. I am guessing there must be an error with the where I stored my js files. in my case I have places it under the plugins folder which is under the "WebContent" of my eclipse. Is that correct?

Comment: You feel or you know? If it can't load any of the files, there would be messages in the console.

Comment: you know wat. I canot seeany chart in eclipse browser but i could see it in firefox and chrome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing everything correct except that you should reference **jquery 1.9** or above version and **jqplot.css** as well here is fiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/K2dLA/

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
<link href="plugins/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="chat3" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>


$(document).ready(function(){
var s1 = [2, 6, 7, 10];
var s2 = [7, 5, 3, 4];
var s3 = [14, 9, 3, 8];
plot3 = $.jqplot('chat3', [s1, s2, s3], {
    // Tell the plot to stack the bars.
stackSeries: true,
captureRightClick: true,
seriesDefaults:{
renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
rendererOptions: {
          // Put a 30 pixel margin between bars.
barMargin: 30,
          // Highlight bars when mouse button pressed.
          // Disables default highlighting on mouse over.
highlightMouseDown: true   
},
pointLabels: {show: true}
},
axes: {
xaxis: {
renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
},
yaxis: {
padMin: 0
}
},
legend: {
show: true,
location: 'e',
placement: 'outside'
}     
});
  // Bind a listener to the "jqplotDataClick" event.  Here, simply change
  // the text of the info3 element to show what series and ponit were
  // clicked along with the data for that point.
$('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataClick',
function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
$('#info3').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
}
);
});
```

Comment: sorry if i sound foolish but i dont find jquery-1.9.1.min.jsfile anywhere in my jqplot folder.

Comment: I have included <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> but not chart itself disappeared.

Comment: try this 
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.js"></script>
and did you referenced jquery.jqplot.css file as well?

Comment: Yes, i included css files too..the actual thing is i could see the bar chart but ideally i should be able to see 3 different color in that, which indicates the different values. After i Include ur cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.js"></script> still it didnt work.

Comment: well i think you have problem with referencing scripts check if they exist in directory that you specified and make sure that div id is the same as plot3 = $.jqplot('this name', [s1, s2, s3], {...});

Comment: I have checked everything..let me put it across this way..what css and js files should be there to get the color on the bar chart?

Comment: shall i change this  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> to <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> ?

Comment: first one is minified version of second but you have to check if there is such folder "Scripts" in your project and jquery-1.9.1.js such js file...

Comment: I got answer finally. All I needed to do was add this line <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>. its done. :) Thanks to everyone who were involved in this discussion. If you find this question useful please mark it up. Thank you. take care.

Comment: guys i came around one more issues, how can i have multiple bars in x axis. to be more clear if my x axis has 5 values namely 1,2,3,4,5. I want in the place of 1 i want to have 3 bars and same in all the point. wat changes i should make to the above code.

Comment: @user2470723 just add additional value for each series, var s1=[2, 6, 7, 10, 5], s2=[7, 5, 3, 4, 5] and so on...

Comment: I am not telling that way. see that would only add an extra bar to the x axis but i wanted some thing like this. please check the image. http://peltiertech.com/Utility/pix/clusterstackchart.png

Comment: if i am not mistaken, this plugin can't do this, you will have to write custom plugin or find another one...

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<div id="plot3" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>
```

to

```
<div id="chart3" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>
```

Comment: there is no error i feel. I am guessing there must be an error with the where I stored my js files. in my case I have places it under the plugins folder which is under the "WebContent" of my eclipse. Is that correct?

Comment: No, i have taken it from here. http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php. and check the last example in that link. now i could see the chart but there is no different colours. Do i have to add anymore css files or something?

Comment: I got answer finally. All I needed to do was add this line <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>. its done. :) Thanks to everyone who were involved in this discussion. If you find this question useful please mark it up. Thank you. take care.

Comment: guys i came around one more issues, how can i have multiple bars in x axis. to be more clear if my x axis has 5 values namely 1,2,3,4,5. I want in the place of 1 i want to have 3 bars and same in all the point. wat changes i should make to the above code.